# For which values of $k$ is there a function that bounds this sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\displaystyle f_n= \frac{1_{[0,n]}}{n^k}$, for $k>0$. For which values of $k$ is there a function $f \in L^1([0, \infty))$ such that $|f_n| \le f$ for all $n$?

I already proved that for $0<k\le 1$ there is no such function cause that would contradict the Dominated Convergence Theorem (is that correct?), but I don't know how to deal the case $k > 1$. Any hints or ideas? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k> 1$. Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1&0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\\x^{-k}&x\geqslant 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that for $k<1$ the there's not such functon?